# Will my daughter, a USA resident, owe Taxes on a UK inheritance?

Tags: united-states, taxes, inheritance, will

My daughter, who now lives in the USA, has inherited some money from her grandmother in the UK. It is approx £25k.

Will she be liable for any tax when it gets transferred to her USA bank account?

Answer (score 9):

No. In the US inheritances are taxed through what is called "estate tax", and it is the estate that pays it. Since in this case the estate is foreign and (assuming) not under the US jurisdiction - there's no US taxes. The heir/recipient is not taxed however there are reporting requirements that kick in when the values reach $100K - your daughter is below that threshold, so no need to even report it.

If, in order to receive it, your daughter ends up needing a bank account in the UK - there would be an FBAR reporting requirement. If the inheritance is delivered directly to her in the US then no need.

Comment: This explains that no taxes are due in the US. Do you know whether any taxes are due in the UK?

Comment: @quarague – in the UK inheritance tax is paid by the estate, similar to the answer above. There are additional taxes that most people resident in the UK are liable for, income tax and capital gains tax. These apply to inheritances too – so if you inherit e.g. shares that pay a dividend you pay income tax on that, or inherit a classic car, keep it for 20 years, and sell it you pay tax on the gain – but are not applicable for people not resident for tax purposes in the UK.

Comment: This is one of the areas of the tax code I find particularly offensive since the person who generated the inheritance likely paid taxes on the income used to fund the inheritance in the first place it always feels like double taxation.

Comment: It is double taxation. Not all taxes are primarily about generating revenue for the state (though that's always a secondary benefit of any tax). Some taxes are designed to discourage certain behaviors, and the behavior being discouraged in this case is "hoarding" wealth to do nothing with it except pass it down from one generation to the next. In the US, at least, there is a rather generous exemption (it was recently raised from "only" $5 million to $11 million).

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss It's also a tax that only affects people with substantial wealth to inherit, which tend to be people that have gotten a lot of advantage from society, versus, say, a sales tax or VAT that takes a disproportionate share of tax from people with lower incomes.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss your assumption that inherited wealth will likely already have been taxed is faulty.  Appreciated assets are taxed only when and if they are sold. If the owner dies without selling them, then when the assets are passed on, the cost basis will be "stepped-up" to the current market value, meaning the inheritor will not pay tax on the appreciation that happened during the benefactor's lifetime. Thus, the estate tax, if any, is the only tax that will ever be paid on those gains. For estates large enough to trigger the tax, most of the estate's value will be in appreciated assets.

Comment: @chepner So using that logic of influencing decisions the "Affordable" Care Act which is effective a "tax" since the IRS runs it instead of say HHS, has had the effect of increasing health care costs and insurance means people purchase less insurance due to that cost increase and sometimes opt for "lessor care" means it was/is designed to do the exact opposite of the name of it.  I guess I am getting way off topic here..sorry

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss hmmm... my experience is that the ACA has significantly lowered the costs of healthcare for those to whom it was previously unaffordable. So yes, no matter how they spin it on Fox News or any other outlet for crazy people, it did exactly what it was supposed to do and exactly in the way it was supposed to do it. I particularly enjoy seeing those who are vehemently defending ACA while denouncing and demanding the repeal of ObamaCare, which happens to be the majority of the Republican voters (you know, the stupid ones, not the assholes)

Comment: In the UK, the standard Inheritance Tax rate is 40%. It is only charged on the part of the estate that is above the tax-free threshold which is currently £325,000. So if someone inherits £425,000, then inheritance tax is due of £40,000 (40% of £100,000). This sum will be deducted from the payment made by the executor or administrator of the estate, following which they pay the inheritor £385,000.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss When money changes hands, taxes are always due. When I get paid I pay income tax, when I then buy something I pay VAT. The store then pays taxes over the money I paid them instead of complaining about “double taxation” since their customers already paid taxes (twice: income _and_ VAT). Maybe inheritance should be exempt for some other reason, but the fact that someone at some point already paid taxes to receive this money, doesn’t exempt the new recipient from paying taxes over it in any other situation. No one actually pays taxes twice here, so it is not double taxation.